# How to store an openpyxl opened image in jpeg format

Tags: python, azure

I'm able to read all the files from an excel but unable to store it in a jpeg format at dest_loc. Suggest

Below is the code:

```
import openpyxl
dest_loc = 'c:/Images/'
file_loc = 'c:/abc.xlsx'
fil = openpyxl.open(file_loc)
imges = [img for sht in fil.worksheets for img in sht._images]
imges
```

output

```
[<openpyxl.drawing.image.Image at 0x7f3a59b75c10>,
 <openpyxl.drawing.image.Image at 0x7f3a902bf220>,
 <openpyxl.drawing.image.Image at 0x7f3a902bfee0>,
 <openpyxl.drawing.image.Image at 0x7f3a902bf160>,
 <openpyxl.drawing.image.Image at 0x7f3a902bfa00>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce and below are my observations:

Firstly, tried your code and got `openpyxl.drawing.image.Image` object image created as it is its functionality:

[image]

Image in excel:

[image]

and I did not find any ways to convert to jpeg, Alternatively if any one wants to convert to PNG you can follow below process:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader as sil

w = load_workbook('path')
s = w['Sheet1']
il = sil(s)
i = il.get('A1')
print(type(i))
i
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rithwik, Actually I don't have the exact cells where images are present like you have passed 'A1'.  In my case images are present on random cells and I need to collect all the images from excel and store it in a blob.

Comment: @Arun, I would suggest you to first get the cell number or names of images and then use my code.